# Cannot Export a Report to a CSV file

Tags: civireport

Since upgrading from CiviCRM 4.4.3 to CiviCRM 5.8.0 last week, I am unable to export my employee training reports to a CSV. The page simply refreshes and doesn't do anything. I have tried making a new report with the same criteria, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Any ideas as to what else I can do?

Comment: hi - if you are wondering if this is a bug it is worth trying to replicate on eg dmaster.demo.civicrm.org - other thoughts are to check if any Permissions have been added. you don't mention what version you upgraded from

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. This occurs when exporting with a user which is not an admin.

As a workaround, I am able to export directly by using the options on the report overview. Can you reproduce that?

[image]